# How can I get JSONarray values from Database through the php and convey the JSONarray to the listview?

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

How can I get JSONarray values from Database through the php and convey the JSONarray to the listview?

Hello, I am making an Android application and I faced some problems that I cannot know what is the cause.

So here is what I want to do. **I wanna get the JSONarray through the php file from the database and show the elements of it into the listview of android.** The array that I wanna get looks like this.

```
[{"success":true,"roomNum":2,"departTime":"2019-07-15 13:30:00","messageText":"학교 정문에서 20분까지 만나요.","peopleNum":2,"placeNum":2},{similar contents}, {similar contents}, {similar contents}]
```

It is the array consisted of another array which has keys and values. To get the array from the database I wrote this php file and It works. (I upload this php file at the DB that I'm using)

```
<?php

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "******", "********", "********");

  $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT roomNum, departTime, messageText, peopleNum, placeNum
    FROM OUTGOING WHERE departTF = FALSE AND peopleNum<4");

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $roomNum, $departTime, $messageText, $peopleNum, $placeNum);


  $response = array();
  $result = array();      

  $response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["roomNum"] = $roomNum;
    $response["departTime"] = $departTime;
    $response["messageText"] = $messageText;
    $response["peopleNum"] = $peopleNum;
    $response["placeNum"] = $placeNum;
    $result[] = $response;
}

  echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);



  mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

However, when I try to get the array into the below class of Android, I cannot see the elements(which are arrays) in the list view. Below codes are the code I wrote. I guess it is the matter of usage of Volley. Can you guys help me?

```
package com.example.sharetaxi;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GagyungActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String[] LIST_MENU = {};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gagyung);


        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String userID = intent.getStringExtra("userID");
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taxilist);
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        Response.Listener<JSONArray> responseListener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray item = response.getJSONArray(i);
                        list.add(item.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        };


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        GagyungRequest gagyungRequest = new GagyungRequest(responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(GagyungActivity.this);
        queue.add(gagyungRequest);
        };


}
```

Here is additional code for the communication with the DB.

```
package com.example.sharetaxi;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GagyungRequest extends JsonArrayRequest{

    final static private String URL = "http://000000000/Listview.php";

    public GagyungRequest(Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener){
        super(Method.POST, URL, null, listener, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: We dont see the listview either   ... so what do you see in your IDE ? logs, stack traces, stuff like that ?

Comment: at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:500)

When I simulate the application, I cannot see the items on the listview. Actually on the longest code, there is the part of the listview. I guess the way of I try to get the item from JsonArray is wrong.. but I don't know which part is wrong. Can you help me?